# Tuning query in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am grouping date ranges with missing dates

```
; With DateRange as
        (
     Select  Col1,Col2,Row_Number() Over (Order by Col1,Col2,FromDate) as RowId,FromDate
 From    #SourceTable R
        Where   Not Exists
                (
                Select  Col1,Col2,FromDate
                From     #SourceTable R1
                where   R1.FromDate = Dateadd(Day, -1, R.FromDate) And R1.Col1=R.Col1 And R1.Col2=R.Col2  
                ) 
        )
 Select  Col1,Col2,DR.FromDate As StartDate
,       (
        Select  Top 1 FromDate 
        From  #SourceTable
        Where   FromDate < COALESCE(
                (
               Select  FromDate
                From    DateRange CR
                Where   DR.RowId + 1 = CR.RowId And DR.Col1=CR.Col1 
                ), '9999-01-01') And Col1=DR.Col1 And Col2=DR.Col2 

           Order by
                FromDate Desc
        ) As EndDate
From    DateRange  DR
Order By Col1,FromDate
```

The above query is working fine. I found this query on StackOverFlow. But the performance is not good can anyone tune that query`?

This is my table structure

```
DBL BB  2014-05-06  Normal Rate
DBL BB  2014-05-07  Normal Rate
DBL BB  2014-05-08  Weekend Rate
DBL BB  2014-05-09  Weekend Rate
DBL BB  2014-05-10  Weekend Rate
DBL BB  2014-05-11  Normal Rate
DBL BB  2014-05-12  Normal Rate
```

I am merging the weekend rate and normal rate

```
DBL    BB    2014-05-06    2014-05-07    Normal Rate
DBL    BB    2014-05-08    2014-05-10    Weekend Rate
DBL    BB    2014-05-11    2014-05-12    Normal Rate
```

> please check this
>    http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/03228/1

Comment: You Really Don't Need To Capitalize Every Single Word In Your Question ....

Comment: And **no** - without knowing your **table structures** (tables, columns, their data types) and your **data** (how many rows? What kind of distribution of the data?) - we cannot tune this for you

Comment: sorry this is my first question i will correct it

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it! That way, you don't need any of those messy HTML table tags, either!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using embeded queries into embeded queries...

You could duplicate the logic you use to find your `FromDate` and change it to get your `EndDate`.

This is way easier on the optimizer (consult the execution plan to see the difference).

```
; With LowerDateRange as
        (
     Select  
          Col1
          ,Col2
          ,Row_Number() Over (Order by Col1,Col2,fromDate, types) as RowId
          ,FromDate
          ,Types
 From    Test R
        Where   Not Exists
                (
                Select  Col1,Col2,FromDate
                From     Test R1
                where   R1.FromDate = Dateadd(Day, -1, R.FromDate) 
                  And R1.Col1=R.Col1 
                  And R1.Col2=R.Col2 
                  And R1.Types=R.Types  
                ) 
        )
,
UpperDateRange as
(
    Select  
          Col1
          ,Col2
          ,Row_Number() Over (Order by Col1,Col2,fromDate, types) as RowId
          ,FromDate as EndDate
          ,Types
 From    Test R
        Where   Not Exists
                (
                Select  Col1,Col2,FromDate
                From     Test R1
                where   R1.FromDate = Dateadd(Day, +1, R.FromDate) 
                  And R1.Col1=R.Col1 
                  And R1.Col2=R.Col2 
                  And R1.Types=R.Types  
                ) 
        )

select l.col1
, l.col2
, l.RowID
, l.FromDate
, u.EndDate
, l.Types 
from LowerDateRange l inner join UpperDateRange u on l.RowID = u.rowID
```

Watch it in action : http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/12c52/1/0

Comment: I added some complexity to the data in the fiddle just to make sure it was working correctly.